# Unable to read csv file that was produced after FileWriter and find duplicate in Java

Tags: java, csv, filereader

I am trying to read the 1st csv file that was created from the FileWriter.

The output of the 1st csv file is the content of entity names (column[1]) that occurs/appear more than 10 times.

After reading the 1st csv file, I am trying to check for duplicates of column[5] (i.e. Tweet token) and write, and add it into the 2nd csv file. 
I tried using the `.contains` method, it does not check the duplicates.

> Update: I have successfully read the file but not able to remove duplicates in `EventDetectionToken()`.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EventDetectioncopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        //1st csv file
        System.out.print("Enter a name for new Tweet Cluster sorting by name entity: ");
        BufferedReader scanName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String newNamefile = scanName.readLine();

        //2nd csv file
        System.out.print("Enter a name for new Tweet Cluster sorting by tweet tokens: ");
        BufferedReader scanToken = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String newTokenfile = scanToken.readLine();

        try {
            eventDetectionName(newNamefile);
            eventDetectionToken(newNamefile, newTokenfile);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
    }

    public static void eventDetectionToken(String fileInput, String fileOuput) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileWriter newCsv = new FileWriter(fileOutput + "." + "csv");
        BufferedWriter newCsvBW = new BufferedWriter(newCsv);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput + ".csv"));
        String data;

        try{
            String temp = null;
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

            do
            {
                data = reader.readLine();
                String tweetToken = null;

                if(data != null)
                {
                    String[] splitText = data.split(",");
                    tweetToken = splitText[5];
                }

                if(temp != null)
                {
                    if(data == null || tweetToken.contains(tweetToken))
                    {
                        if(!(temp.equals(tweetToken)))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i ++)
                            {
                                newCsvBW.append(tempList.get(i));
                                newCsvBW.append("\n");
                                System.out.println(tempList.get(i));
                            }
                         }

                        tempList.clear();
                        temp = tweetToken;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = tweetToken;
                }
                tempList.add(data);
            }
            while(data != null);
        }
        finally
        {
            newCsvBW.close();
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public static void eventDetectionName(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String csv = "1day/clusters.sortedby.clusterid.csv";
        FileWriter newCsv = new FileWriter(filename + "." + "csv");
        BufferedWriter newCsvBW = new BufferedWriter(newCsv);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
        String data;

        try{
            String temp = null;
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Long> tempTime = new ArrayList<Long>();
            do 
            {
                data = reader.readLine();
                String nameEntity = null;
                if (data != null) 
                {
                    String[] splitText = data.split(",");
                    nameEntity = splitText[1];
                }
                if (temp != null) 
                {
                    if (data == null || !(nameEntity.equals(temp))) 
                    {
                        if (tempList.size() >= 10) 
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) 
                            {
                                newCsvBW.append(tempList.get(i));
                                newCsvBW.append("\n");
                                System.out.println(tempList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        tempList.clear();
                        temp = nameEntity;
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    temp = nameEntity;
                }
                tempList.add(data);
            } 
            while (data != null);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.close();
            newCsvBW.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Below is some content of the original csv file: "clusters.sortedby.clusterid.csv", before running `EventDetectioncopy.java` with duplicate tweet tokens (column[5]):
[clusterid], [name entity], [tweetid], [timestamp], [userid], [tweet token], [tweet text]

```
1   rick ross   2.5582E+17  1.34983E+12 389746870   rick ross dice pineappl Rick Ross x diced pineapples
1   rick ross   2.5582E+17  1.34983E+12 56082039    dice pineappl uhhh rick ross voic   Diced Pineapples. UHHH *Rick Ross voice*
1   rick ross   2.55821E+17 1.34983E+12 870278689   rick ross trend Why is Rick Ross trending?
1   rick ross   2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 379948188   lmfao rick ross grunt   Lmfao he did that rick ross grunt .
1   rick ross   2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 276594374   play rick ross  they played w| rick ross !
1   rick ross   2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 386219877   rick ross ugli  Rick Ross So Ugly ..
1   rick ross   2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 53327754    wanna play rick ross belli  I Wanna Play in Rick Ross Belly..!
1   rick ross   2.55824E+17 1.34983E+12 19690034    rick ross dice pineappl ft wale amp drake video via laleak  Rick Ross - Diced Pineapples ft. Wale &amp; Drake (Video) via @laleakers
1   rick ross   2.55825E+17 1.34983E+12 357250991   husband rick ross   where my husband rick ross î„…î‰
1   rick ross   2.55825E+17 1.34983E+12 53734179    throw rick ross kirko bangz *Throws Rick ross At Kirko Bangz*
1   rick ross   2.55825E+17 1.34983E+12 462179553   rick ross stay fresh    Rick Ross Stay Fresh!!!!
1   rick ross   2.55827E+17 1.34983E+12 46744853    offici music video dice pineappl rick ross drake wale   Official Music Video " Diced Pineapples" Rick Ross / Drake / Wale
1   rick ross   2.55829E+17 1.34983E+12 461725574   saw rick ross uhhh ifxckgaygirl dadd    i saw rick ross their .. uhhh @ifxckgaygirls dadd :p
1   rick ross   2.55832E+17 1.34983E+12 283244204   rick ross wavi fat guy  Rick Ross is a wavy fat guy
1   rick ross   2.55832E+17 1.34983E+12 528834435   rick ross dice pineappl Rick Ross - Diced Pineapples
1   rick ross   2.55835E+17 1.34983E+12 463279022   rick ross featur wale amp drake dice pineappl ricki ross experi downtim less 24 hour    Rick Ross featuring Wale &amp; Drake â€“ Diced Pineapples:   Ricky Ross experiences no downtime as less than 24 hours ...
1   rick ross   2.55835E+17 1.34983E+12 28460245    yuck lalasodiddi need husband rick ross take award home hiphiopaward    YUCK! RT @LalaSoDiddy: I need my husband Rick Ross to take some awards home #HipHiopAwards
1   rick ross   2.55836E+17 1.34983E+12 330811468   kingkennzi rick ross round  â€œ@KingKennzie: Rick Ross is very round.â€ ðŸ
1   rick ross   2.55836E+17 1.34983E+12 124024753   rick ross titti Rick Ross Titties!
1   rick ross   2.55836E+17 1.34983E+12 765822380   rick ross titti tho Rick Ross and them titties tho!!!
2   tyler oakley    2.55821E+17 1.34983E+12 867420925   know someth trend new asktyl tyleroakley live   HOW DO YOU KNOW WHEN SOMETHING IS TRENDING? IM NEW TO THIS... #aSKTYLER
2   tyler oakley    2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 504044044   asktyl get perfect quiff tyleroakley live   #AskTyler How do you get a perfect quiff :)?
2   tyler oakley    2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 709347721   asktyl realli homework right now tyleroakley live   #asktyler i really should be doing homework right now
2   tyler oakley    2.55822E+17 1.34983E+12 171667747   obsess right now asktyl tyleroakley live    what is your obsession right now? #asktyler
3   wiz khalifa 2.5582E+17  1.34983E+12 588829718   dont like wiz khalifa look sexi I don't like Wiz Khalifa but he looks sexy.
3   wiz khalifa 2.55856E+17 1.34984E+12 502086440   feel like wiz khalifa right now I feel like wiz Khalifa right now..
3   wiz khalifa 2.55866E+17 1.34984E+12 446056049   like wiz khalifa hes ador realli look like hot cheeto man thingi    I like Wiz Khalifa he's adorable, but he really do look like the hot cheeto man thingy
3   wiz khalifa 2.55883E+17 1.34984E+12 67747115    np ne yo ft wiz khalifa dont make em like   #Np Ne-Yo ft. Wiz Khalifa - They don't make em like you
```

> Update: How can I remove the duplicates of it?

Comment: Have you tried walking through your code with a debugger?

Comment: The real question here is "Why is Rick Ross trending?"

Comment: @Synch the FileReader in `eventDetectionToken` function is unable to read the `String newNamefile` which is the 1st csv file that was created. How can I read the 1st csv file in `eventDetectionToken` function?

Comment: Your csv file is tab-delimited but you're splitting on a comma.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou previously without the `eventDetectionToken` function, I am able to read the original csv file and write it into the 1st csv file.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy the entity name occurs more than 10 times

Comment: Your code looks very convoluted and over-complicated. If you could simplify it, I might understand what it's trying to do. Some tips: (1) use meaningful names. Avoid 'temp'. Methods that return void should be verbs, not nouns. The verb should say what the method does. (2) Use try-with-resouces instead of closing in a 'finally' block. (3) Don't create unused variables (such as 'tempTime'). (4) Make sure your code compiles without any compiler errors before you post. Your code shown above has a compiler error and won't run. (5) Use `PrintWriter.println` instead of `BufferedWriter.append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: it will delete all duplicates and leave only one item.

```
public static void eventDetectionToken(String fileInput, String fileOuput)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileWriter newCsv = new FileWriter(fileOuput + "." + "csv");
    BufferedWriter newCsvBW = new BufferedWriter(newCsv);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput + ".csv"));
    String data;

    try {
        List<String> existanceTokens = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {
            data = reader.readLine();
            String tweetToken = null;

            if (data != null) {
                String[] splitText = data.split(",");
                tweetToken = splitText[5];

                if (!(existanceTokens.contains(tweetToken))) {
                    newCsvBW.append(data);
                    newCsvBW.append("\n");
                    existanceTokens.add(tweetToken);
                }
            }
        } while (data != null);
    } finally {
        newCsvBW.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

---

But if you want firstly create CSV file with duplicates by [name entity] and than based on this file create second one with duplicates by [tweet token], need to change `inputCSV` to `newNamefile` for second `eventDetection` invokation like this:

```
    eventDetection(inputCSV, newNamefile, 1);
    eventDetection(newNamefile, newTokenfile, 5);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried but the supposed output (csv files) was not created

Comment: Do you mean file was not created at all? Or it was created but contains wrong data?

Comment: the file was not created at all

Comment: This code should create 2 files which are located inside your Project root folder if you provide input like "file name" without full path.
Please check your Project root folder (it's not src folder where .java files are placed, it's upper folder)

Comment: BTW here is example of work performed
Input file:
1,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,22,1
2,jack,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,33,2
3,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,2234,3
4,john,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,4
5,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,2332,5
6,john,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,22,6

Comment: first file created by eventDetection(inputCSV, newNamefile, 1);
1,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,1
3,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,3
5,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,5
4,john,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,4
6,john,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,389746870,6

second file created by eventDetection(inputCSV, newTokenfile, 5);
1,rick,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,22,1
6,john,ross,2.5582E+17,1.34983E+12,22,6

Comment: Is there another to remove duplicates using the code in the question?

Comment: Your code in a do-while loop comparing each current tweetToken with previous one which is stores in temp variable. It means it will append to the 2nd file only if current token doesn't equal to previous one. So it will ignore duplicate items which are following one by one only. You need to do something like my code does.
1. Read whole input CSV file
2. Iterate over each line
3. Compare each line to each following lines using new loop inside.
4. Make a decison inside nested loop

Comment: You need to do such kind of logic for both eventDetectionName and eventDetectionToken methods. Because for now your first file contains only entities which are following one by one more than 10 times. But if somewhere bellow in the file there will be more entities with the same column[1] apprearing less than 10 times thay will be just skipped instead of adding to the first file.

Comment: Is it possible to have one method that includes (reading whole input csv file, iterating over each line, comparing each line and making the decision), and not have so many methods like your code?

Comment: It works. Thank you. U mentioned that my eventDetectionName method logic is incorrect?

Comment: The eventDetectionName method is to find the entity name for each cluster id which occurs more than 10 times and add it into the new csv file (2nd csv file).

Comment: I tried running 2 types of csv file. A 1 day csv file that was used to process eventDetectionName method contains 14560 rows after the method was executed while another csv file which contains much more content, is the 7 days csv file, and the output of rows contains 59862 after eventDetectionName method was executed.

Comment: The 1 day csv file (14560 rows) is able use the above method that was given by you to remove duplicates. For the 7 days csv file (59862 rows), duplicates are removed, but some content with no duplicates were removed too. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Regarding to eventDetectionName() method. Here is situation:
- file contains 12 lines with cluster id equals "rick" placed one by one
* method will write these 12 lines to the new file
- after these lines there are lines with some other cluster id's.
- after that there are 7 lines with cluster id equals "rick" placed one by one
* method will not write these additional 7 lines to the previous 12 with the same cluster id. It will skip because 7 < 10. If it's what is expected or you will never get such kind of situation, so it's Ok.

Comment: But if it's expected that 12+7=19 lines with cluster id equals "rick" should be handled, need to change logic of method accoringly

Comment: Regarding 7 days csv file (59862 rows). If content is lost just at the end of the file, you need to add newCsvBW.flush(); just before newCsvBW.close();
But if contents is lost somewhere in the middle of the file - it's hard to say what is a problem. Need to debug it with this big file in order to examine what is going wrong. It can be problem with CSV file itself, for example.

Comment: I think the content is lost between rows 14560 to 59862. I don't think the csv file have problem as it was provided. Do you want to take a look at the content of the 7 days csv file?

Comment: Let's try. May be need to create chat or smth. like that. Posting comments is not so convenient

Comment: How can we create a chat?

Comment: During commenting here there is "automatically move this discussion to chat" link, but following it I don't have enough reputation yet (only 16 of 20)

Comment: So there’s no other way to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159611/discussion-between-user7146946-and-kyrya).

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is `FileReader` unable to read `newNamefile`?

That is because the variable `newNamefile` in

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newNamefile));
```

does not exist in the scope of `EventDetectioncopy#eventDetectionToken`.

#### Proposed solution

Change the variable to match the parameter in the method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Comment: I tried using the proposed solution, but it still does not read in the 1st csv file that was created.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String csvFile = csvFilePath1;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedReader br1 = null;
        String line = "";
        String csv = csvFilePath;
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(csv);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath1));
            int headerRow = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i <= headerRow; i++) {
                fileWriter.append(br1.readLine() + "\n");
            }
            br1.close();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lines.add(line) && lines.size() >= 5) {
                    fileWriter.append(line);
                    fileWriter.append("\n");
                }
            }
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain what `csvFilePath1` and `csvFilePath` represents?

Comment: csvFilePath and csvFilePath1 like 1st csv file and 2nd csv file. This code help you remove duplicate row, you can change to check duplicate row :)

Comment: I am able to read the file now, but unable to remove duplicate. I have edited the code in my question. Hope it helps

Comment: cause your row not duplicate :) You can try by use exel: Go tab data->removeduplicates.

Comment: the criteria for this project is to remove duplicates using code and not via excel itself.

Comment: i mean you check your row is duplicate or not :( If duplicate parts of row different with duplicate row. Now i'm busy and can't check your code more detail, but i think your csv not duplicate row.

Comment: there are duplicate for the column[5] but i need to remove the row that have duplicate of column[5]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159607/discussion-between-user7146946-and-phuong-buon).